# Modal opening at bottom of longer pages, not top

Tags: html, css, modal-dialog

I have a relatively simple modal (i've dumbed down the content for this question) which is made of an overlay, a modal container and then the modal itself.

It works as expected except for the fact that on longer pages that need to be scrolled through, it shows at the bottom of the page. I've altered the CSS several times to no avail

How can I make it so that this modal opens at the top area of the page no matter what?

```css
.modal-vue {
  display: block;
}

.modal-vue .overlay {
  text-align: center;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 9998;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}

.modal-vue .modal {
  position: relative;
  width: 80%;
  z-index: 9999;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 20px 30px;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin-top: -20%;
}

.modal-vue .close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div style="height:1200px;">

</div>

<div class="modal-vue">
  <!-- overlay to help with readability of modal -->
  <div class="overlay"></div>
  <!-- Modal for detail on table cell click event -->
  <div class="modal">
    <button class="close">x</button>
    <div class="uk-grid">
      <!-- Starting real modal body for iteration now -->
      <div class="uk-width-5-10" style="margin-bottom:60px;">
        <div class="md-card">
          <div class="md-card-toolbar">
            TEST
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!--end modal-->
    </div>
    <!--end modal overlay-->
  </div>
  <!--end modal-vue-->
```

Comment: Don't you need to put modal inside overlay?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/alvaromenendez/bz0ge6vc/3/  ???  always center of viewport. if you want it at top just change the top value and remove translateY

Comment: You are right @AlvaroMenéndez, it is a typo. User don't use the `overlay` div closing tag at right place

Comment: @AlvaroMenéndez so all you did was wrap the modal in the overlay div?

Comment: And adjust some css's.

Comment: Ah i see, thanks for that. i think I see why that wasn't working now, besides the closing div error

Answer (score 0):

**HTML:**

```
<div style="height:1200px;">

</div>
  <div class="overlay"  >
<div class="modal-vue" >
  <!-- overlay to help with readability of modal -->

  <!-- Modal for detail on table cell click event -->
  <div class="modal">
     <button class="close" >x</button>
     <div class="uk-grid">
        <!-- Starting real modal body for iteration now -->
        <div class="uk-width-5-10"  style="margin-bottom:60px;">
           <div class="md-card">
              <div class="md-card-toolbar">
                 TEST
              </div>
           </div>
        </div>
        <!--end modal-->
     </div>
     <!--end modal overlay-->
  </div>
  <!--end modal-vue-->
  </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
body{
  margin:0;
}
.modal-vue{
  display: flex;
  justify-content:start;
  height:100vh;
  align-items:start;
}

.modal-vue .overlay {
  text-align: center;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 9998;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}

.modal-vue .modal {
  position: relative;
  width: 80%;
  z-index: 9999;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 20px 30px;
  background-color: #fff;
 margin-top:2rem;
}

.modal-vue .close{
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px;
}
```

Link to jsfiddle -> http://jsfiddle.net/Markov88/u9eq2oh3/23/

Comment: No that's the whole point, the  1200px height div represents a div that extends beyond the page-load viewpoint. I want to make sure that the modal will always load at the center of the viewpoint no matter how long the page has gotten

Comment: check edited post pls